# Django form not showing when importing it to html

Tags: python, html, django

Trying to import a Django form into an html template, but it's not showing up, and nothing on here is working. I feel like i've exhausted every solution on this site and nothing. Any ideas?

views.py

```
def saveFileUpload(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        capturedForm = UploadFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if capturedForm.is_valid():
            capturedForm.save()
        else:
            capturedForm = UploadFileForm()
        context['form'] = capturedForm
        return render(request, 'fileupload.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"
```

fileupload.html

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">{%  csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have not included all your code for the saveFileUpload view, there is nothing to display if your `request.method` does *not* equal `POST`. Here is a cleaner way to do all you need:

```py
def saveFileUpload(request):
    capturedForm = UploadFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if capturedForm.is_valid():
        capturedForm.save()
        return redirect('a-view-to-redirect-to')
    context['form'] = capturedForm
    return render(request, 'fileupload.html', context)
```

You won't need the

```py
else:
    capturedForm = UploadFileForm()
```

or the

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
```

since you already defined

```py
capturedForm = UploadFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

This will mean that if it is *NOT* a POST request, the capturedForm will be None instead of request.POST.

Now the `return redirect('a-view-to-redirect-to')` can be the url path name defined in your urls.py for the same view that sent the form, or any other view.